# Google maps API - Get Capital city

Tags: api, maps

when i ask google maps api for the lat lng of a country (ex.: Turkey) it returns the geometric center of this country.
i want to know if google maps api can return the lat lng of the capital city.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, if this data is not in xml response, then the google does not support.

If you need coordination only a few city then you can use just google maps

https://www.google.cz/maps/@39.9165691,32.8214354,12z

and mouse right click - what is here, and in finded box you get name of city and his coordination    39.930919, 32.844781